# how to call another class from existing web service class in java using restful jersey implementation

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

i created a class named `RestApi` and a method `acceptFourParam`  which accepts four parameters from clients like (google or Boomerang which is google extension) and insert them to Microsoft SQL server database.

Parameters are received from user using `@queryparam` and printing result on console is working properly till insertion into database. After that, I need to call another class from my existing class in restful web service using jersey.

i created an object of  `CellNumberWebService` class in `RestApi` class and then by using `CellNumberWebService` object i call its method and pass cellnumber arugment but its not working .  like normal java calling of class i also do here but in restful it not working.

i imported all need libraries but have removed them from here for better readability.

```
cellNumberWebService.cellNumberToPrint(cell_number);
```

Code snippet:

```
package test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import test.CellNumberWebService;

@Path("/restApi")
public class RestfulApi {

    Connection connection;
    Statement statement;
    CellNumberWebService cellNumberWebService;

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();



    @GET
    @Path("/param")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public void acceptFourParam(@QueryParam("action_name") String action_name, @QueryParam("card_number")
                                 int card_number, @QueryParam("cell_number") int cell_number , @QueryParam("sms_verification") String sms_verification){

        cellNumberWebService.cellNumberToPrint(cell_number);            

        if(action_name.equals(null) || card_number == 0 || cell_number == 0 || sms_verification.equals(null) ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please provide all information:");
        } else {
            try {               
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                //System.out.println("driver loaded successfully");
                connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=RestApi;user=sa;password=coder182");
                //System.out.println("Connection created successfully");
                statement=connection.createStatement();

                String query ="insert into User_information(action_name, card_number , cell_number ,sms_verification ,  inserted_date_time)" + "values ('"+action_name+"','"+card_number+"', '"+cell_number+"' , '"+sms_verification+"', '"+now+"');";
                statement.executeUpdate(query);
            } catch(Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

package test;

public class CellNumberWebService {

    public void cellNumberToPrint(int cellNumber) {
        System.out.println("Cell number of user is " + cellNumber);
    }
}
```

`CellNumberWebService`  is the class that I need to call from  `RestfulApi.cellNumberToPrint` method to accept cellnumber argument which we are passing from `ResfulApi`. This parameter is set in acceptFourParam method.

Comment: When you use Jersey, you often also use HK2 as you DI-Framework. Add `@Inject` to the field to prevent the NPE. Also, you `@Produces` HTML, but return `void`.

Comment: @Rainer i know its damn but for time being i do this.... i am using jersay jax-rs to consume web service....so tell me or refer me links from where i solve my problem .thank you

Comment: @sfiss is there any way to solve this problem except DI.? please refer some links either google or youtube by which i learn and solve this problem ..

Comment: Sure, use a constructor or `CellNumberWebService cellNumberWebService = new CellNumberWebService()`. Just do it the old, not really good way while you familiarize yourself with dependency injection (the concept, not necessarily a framework).

Comment: @sfiss thanks it working. yes i started dependency injection concept ... again thanks for suggesting DI.